# VBA: Cannot assign values to an array in a loop

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop, valueerror

I am modelling populations of cicadas and predators for mathematical biology and I have a problem to assign a value to a 2D array called predator. It always responses with #value error in a cell.

I am sorry that I send a bit longer code but I'm not sure what is responsible for the problem (I feel quite sure that it's in the "Update" part but there are references to the rest of the code). I have already tried to delete the code for "Scalar product for predators" and "Updating newborn predators" and the rest of the code then works at least for getting value from cicada array (asking for `CicSurvP = cicada(1,0)`)

I would appreciate any help since the code for a predator seems similar to the working code for a cicada and I do not know what could be wrong.

```
'Distributions
Function OneX(k As Integer, i As Integer) As Double
    OneX = 1
End Function

Function Z_oneX(k As Integer, i As Integer) As Double
If i = 0 Then
    Z_oneX = 0
Else
    Z_oneX = 1
End If
End Function

'body
Function CicSurvP(c_length As Integer, p_length As Integer, c_surv As Double, p_surv As Double, c_danger As Double, p_meal As Double, c_baby As Double, p_baby As Double, c_max As Double, p_max As Double, c_init As Double, p_init As Double, length As Integer, ext As Double) As Double

'Declare variables
c_length = c_length - 1
p_length = p_length - 1
Dim cicada() As Double
Dim predator() As Double
ReDim cicada(length, c_length)
ReDim predator(length, p_length)
Dim c_temp As Double
Dim p_temp As Double
Dim p_t As Double
Dim c_t As Double
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

'Initiation
For i = 0 To c_length
    cicada(0, i) = c_init '*dist(i) multiply by the chosen distribution
Next
For i = 0 To p_length
    predator(0, i) = p_init '*dist(i) multiply by the chosen distribution
Next

'Update
For n = 0 To length - 1
    'Update cicada
    For i = 0 To c_length - 1
        cicada(n + 1, i + 1) = cicada(n, i) * c_surv
    Next
    'Update predator
    For i = 0 To p_length - 1
        If p_surv + p_meal * cicada(n, c_length) < 1 Then
            predator(n + 1, i + 1) = predator(n, i) * (p_surv + p_meal * cicada(n, c_length))
        Else
            predator(n + 1, i + 1) = predator(n, i)
        End If
    Next
    'Scalar product for cicada
    c_t = 0
    For i = 0 To p_length
        c_t = c_t + OneX(p_length, i) * predator(n, i)
    Next
    'Scalar product for predator
    p_t = 0
    For i = 0 To p_length
        p_t = p_t + Z_oneX(p_length, i) * predator(n, i)
    Next
    'Update newborn cicadas
    c_temp = c_surv * (c_baby - c_danger * c_t / cicada(n, c_length)) * cicada(n, c_length)
    If c_temp <= 0 Then
        cicada(n + 1, 0) = 0
    ElseIf c_temp <= c_max Then
        cicada(n + 1, 0) = c_temp
    Else
        cicada(n + 1, 0) = c_max
    End If
    'Update newborn predators
    p_temp = (p_surv + p_meal * cicada(n, c_length)) * p_baby * p_t
    If p_temp <= p_max Then
        predator(n + 1, 0) = p_temp
    Else
        predator(n + 1, 0) = p_max
    End If
Next
CicSurvP = predator(1,0)
End Function
```

Comment: Can you update the question to show the parameters you are passing to the function.  That will allow us to step through your code to see where it errors.

Comment: The best way to debug a UDF is to call it from a sub instead of from a worksheet: when called from a sub it will break and show you the problem line(s).